# Kuberentes plugin - Unable to install kubectl flame in M1 Mac

Tags: kubectl, apple-m1

Getting below error when I am trying to install kubectl-flame in M1 Mac.

https://github.com/yahoo/kubectl-flame#installing

kubectl krew install flame

Installing plugin: flame
W0209 12:58:16.250359   60217 install.go:164] failed to install plugin "flame": plugin "flame" does not offer installation for this platform
failed to install some plugins: [flame]: plugin "flame" does not offer installation for this platform.

Any workarounds to install this successfully?

Comment: https://github.com/yahoo/kubectl-flame/issues/74

Comment: thanks.
KREW_OS="darwin" KREW_ARCH="amd64" kubectl krew install flame
this works.

Comment: I get the following error when I try to profile a pod. What could have gone wrong?

type":"error","data":{"reason":"open /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/layerdb/mounts/containerd://1624e12dbe6c6a5442b12fd57d5be39d95626be79e370aa06e3a2828bea3561c/mount-id: no such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

Setting KREW_OS and KREW_ARCH worked.

KREW_OS="darwin" KREW_ARCH="amd64" kubectl krew install flame